# Content Security Policy meta tag within sandboxed iframe not working in Safari (14.0.2)

Tags: security, iframe, safari, sandbox

I'm trying to embed a page whose Content Security Policy does not seem to be respected in Safari, but does works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Brave. The embed looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmUiDhFZeFnJvHgxGbwPucT8kyZvAzBsFFA12vPNxfsP6u/" sandbox="allow-scripts" />
```

The embedded page looks like this, and contains a CSP meta tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSP should dictate that the page can load resources from its own origin, as well as inline scripts. However, when I try to load the iframe in Safari, I get an error claiming the path to the script does not match the `default-src` directive:

```
Refused to load https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmUiDhFZeFnJvHgxGbwPucT8kyZvAzBsFFA12vPNxfsP6u/test.js because it appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

The response headers for the embedded page look like this:
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbqvI.png)

Here is a simple jsfiddle demostrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4hLdygm9/1/

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Have open an issue on the Webkit Bugzilla and has been confirmed to be a bug:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=223848

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Comment: Seems to be a webkit bug (update above)

Comment: Yup, i'm seeing this too, looks to be still unresolved